# UIScrollView return to its original place

Tags: objective-c, xcode, uiscrollview

I have the following code:

```
float yOffset = activeTextView.frame.origin.y - keyboardSize.height + 55;
        CGPoint scrollPoint = CGPointMake(0.0, yOffset);
        [scrollView setContentOffset:scrollPoint animated:YES];
```

This animates the scrollView in `- (void)keyboardWasShown:(NSNotification *)notification`

I am trying to return the scrollView to it's original location after the hiding the keyboard like this:

```
- (void) keyboardWillHide:(NSNotification *)notification {

    UIEdgeInsets contentInsets = UIEdgeInsetsZero;
    scrollView.contentInset = contentInsets;
    scrollView.scrollIndicatorInsets = contentInsets;

}
```

But it doesn't work!

How can I return the UIScrollView and actually the whole screen to its original location so the user will see what he saw before animation of the scrollview?

Comment: I don't see any code where you're registering for UIKeyboardWillHideNotification.  How is your -keyboardWillHide: method getting invoked?

Comment: I register in viewDidLoad  [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                             selector:@selector(keyboardWasShown:)
                                                 name:UIKeyboardDidShowNotification
                                               object:nil];
    
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                             selector:@selector(keyboardWillHide:)
                                                 name:UIKeyboardWillHideNotification
                                               object:nil];

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your `keyboardWasShown:` method, you're setting the `contentOffset` property (`[scrollView setContentOffset:]` is equivalent to `scrollView.contentOffset`). However, in `keyboardWillHide:`, you're setting `contentInset`, which is something completely different (essentially, it's the amount of internal padding of the scroll view's content). Try

```
scrollView.contentOffset = CGPointZero; // non-animated by default
```

or

```
[scrollView setContentOffset:CGPointZero animated:YES]; // animated
```

Also, as NSResponder mentioned, make sure your `keyboardWillHide:` method is being called.

Comment: This does not work, as it also scrolls the scrollView to the top.

Comment: That is what this code is designed to do - questions of this nature usually have the unscrolled position of the scrollView indicating what the screen should look like usually, and shift everything when the keyboard is opened. If you're also using the `scrollView` for other behavior and want it to return to the previous position, store the `contentOffset` value into a `CGPoint` class property or variable, and replace `CGPointZero` in my answer with that variable when you hide the keyboard.